# Absolutely Homogenous Functions on Normed Spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I was given the following problem and am lost for where to start.

Let $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ be the real vector space of $m$-tuples of real numbers and let $\Vert \cdot \Vert : \mathbb{R}^{m} \to [0,\infty)$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. Let $f: (\mathbb{R}^{m}, \Vert \cdot \Vert) \to (\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ be a continuous function with $f(\mathbf{x})>0$ for all non zero $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$. Show that if $f$ is absolutely homogenous (i.e. $f(t\mathbf{x})=|t|f(\mathbf{x})$ for every real $t$ and every $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$) then there exists a positive constant $\alpha > 0$ such that $\alpha \Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert \leq f(\mathbf{x})$ for every  $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$

As I said I have no idea even where to start for this. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: What about $f \equiv 0$?

Comment: Apologies @PhoemueX, I had forgotten to put a piece of the question in that stipulate that f>0 for all non 0 x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent, which in particular implies that the set $C = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^m: \|x\|=1\}$ is compact. The continuous function $f$ must attain a minimum on $C$ which is strictly positive, say $0<c = \min_{x\in C}f(x)$.

Then if $x\in \mathbb{R}^m\setminus \{0\}$ is arbitrary we conclude that

$$c\leq f(x/\|x\|) = \frac{1}{\|x\|}f(x)$$
since $x/\|x\|\in C$.

Comment: I had literally just noticed this and was about to type out basically the same thing, thank you!!